# Facebook api 5V get email

Tags: php, html, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am having troubles with getting email address from Facebook sdk using php.

error message:

> Notice: Undefined variable: request in
>   /storage/h5/727/1013727/public_html/index.php on line 94
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on
>   null in /storage/h5/727/1013727/public_html/index.php:94 Stack trace:
>
> 0 {main} thrown in /storage/h5/727/1013727/public_html/index.php on
>   line 94

my code is:

```
    <?php
  /* PHP SDK v5.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{email}'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
    ?>
```

the only thing i require is :

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-sdk-v5/autoload.php';
```

should i make a config.php that loads everything? and if so is there something on git that you know because i cant find one **(V5)**

Comment: check if file exist with file_exists function

Answer (score 0):

From the official [Facebook PHP SDK documentation](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk), you should be doing:

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
  //'default_access_token' => '{access-token}', // optional
]);

$response = $fb->get('/{user-id}?fields=email', '{access-token}');

$user = $response->getGraphUser();
```

Comment: i get this error: fatal error: Uncaught Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookAuthenticationException: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: email in ....

Comment: That error is because the `email` in `/email` is not a valid API call. You need to call `/{user-id}`. See https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Demail&version=v2.8